# Excel - lock the formula with internal link and make it invisible

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following problem:

Once I embedded the link inside the text as follows:

```
  ="Photograph indicates the entrance elevation of "&Frontsheet!D27&"."
```

I am getting an awkward result as follows:

[image]

once I start editing the text.

Is there any way to hide this formula and type the text as normal?

I tried to lock the cells and sheets, but it wasn't helpful for me.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I tried reproduce this issue but everything seems to be working fine here. Can you disable all macros and try again?

Comment: I cannot, because I have the VBA macros throughout the document. I would appreciate any suggestion including VBA too.

Comment: I have the impression that your question becomes "Excel launches a macro producing undesired results, how can I know which macro is being used currently?".

Comment: The formula, what I showed is not a macro. It's a simple way to make an internal link within the text, that can be saved in the .xslx folder. I am looking for the solution, how to make the text unscathed and the formula hidden. Is that possible at all?